# how to position a uiview always on bottom rigth corner in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I working on custom view which is added as subview to UIWindow. I want to make that custom view always on top of any view in app and user can interact any view behind the custom view. Now custom view is appearing on top after added in window but problem is custom view disappearing if any view presented modally now. So please help me the find the logic every time whenever any added over my custom view then my custom view should come front of new view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a singleton class may be named as 'Utils'
2. Put below method into 'Utils' class (you should customize the 'view' object as required.

`static const NSString * StickyView  = @"StickyView";`

```
-(void)displaySticky
    {
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIWindow *mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

            UIView *existingView = (UIView *)objc_getAssociatedObject(mainWindow, &StickyView);
            if (existingView != nil)
            {

                [mainWindow bringSubviewToFront:existingView];
                return;
            }

            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 125)];
            view.center = CGPointMake(mainWindow.bounds.size.width-150/2,mainWindow.bounds.size.height-125/2);


            objc_setAssociatedObject (mainWindow, &StickyView, view, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

            [mainWindow addSubview:view];
            [mainWindow bringSubviewToFront:view];

        });

        }
```

3. Now you should call that method in 'viewDidAppear' of all of your ViewController classes as below

   `[[Utils sharedInstance] displaySticky];`//assuming your singleton class's instance method is 'sharedInstance'